# Vue.js use correct component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a **main-component** in that **main-component** I've a **sub-component** with `vue.js 2.0`.

The problem is that the **sub-component** uses the methods in the **main-component**.

I've made an example:

```js
Vue.component('main-component', {
  template: '<p>This is the main component. <sub-component><button @click="test()">If this button is presses: "sub-component" must show up. </button></sub-component></p>',
  methods: {
   test() {
        alert('main-component');
        }
  }
})

Vue.component('sub-component', {
  template: '<p>This is sub-component <slot></slot> </p>',
  methods: {
       test() {
       alert('sub-component');
      }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <main-component></main-component>
</div>
```

How do I make sure the `sub-component` uses it's own methods, and in this case give an alert of: 'sub-component' instead of 'main-component' when the button is being pressed?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: I do not think so.

Comment: Looks like it's a good time to introduce vuex

Comment: You have a couple of answers below. Can we get some feedback on whether either of them worked for you?

Comment: @BertEvans whoops sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

```js
Vue.component('main-component', {
  template:  `
    <p>This is the main component. 
      <sub-component>
        <template scope="{test}">
          <button @click="test()">If this button is presses: "sub-component" must show up. </button>
        </template>
      </sub-component>
    </p>`,
  methods: {
    test() {
           alert('main-component');
        }
  }
})

Vue.component('sub-component', {
  template: '<p>This is sub-component <slot :test="test"></slot> </p>',
  methods: {
       test() {
        alert('sub-component');
      }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <main-component></main-component>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jamie No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
<sub-component ref="sub"><button @click="$refs.sub.test()">...</button></sub-component>
```